# How do you write an insertion statement (SQL) for IS-A relationships?

Tags: sql

I have a IS-A relationship between actor and person.

I understand how to write an insertion statement for PERSON. But how would I connect that 
to ACTOR?

EDIT: To clarify, is there a way to do this besides setting the relationship manually?

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  person_id     INT,
  person_name   VARCHAR(20),
  birth_year    CHAR(4),
  gender        CHAR(1),
  PRIMARY KEY(person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE actor
(
  actor_id      INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person(person_id),
  PRIMARY KEY(actor_id)
);
```

Comment: Use a database that supports that paradigm(oop,inheritance).  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends how you are determining who is an actor.  If you already know this at the time of insertion into the person table, then you can just use another INSERT statement to insert the row into the actor table as well.

If you already have the person table defined and want to identify particular people and tag them as actors (i.e. by name), you could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO actor (actor_id) 
  SELECT person_id    
  FROM person
  WHERE person_name = 'Will Smith';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce898/9

Either way, as long as the actor_id in actor matches a valid person_id in person, the INSERT will be valid.  If no corresponding person_id exists, the INSERT will fail.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. Would I have to also do the same for deleting statements even when the relationship is established?

Answer (score 2):

If in case you are using Postgres, you can do inheritance, just like in OOP:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  person_id     serial primary key,
  person_name   VARCHAR(20),
  birth_year    CHAR(4),
  gender        CHAR(1)
);


create table actor
(
  role text
) inherits(person);
```

Test:

```
insert into person(person_name,birth_year,gender)
values('john lennon','1940','M');


insert into actor(person_name,birth_year,gender,role)
values('johnny depp','19xx','M','hacker');


insert into actor(person_name,birth_year,gender,role)
values('johnny walker','19xx','M','walker');


select * from person order by person_name;

select * from actor order by person_name;


Output:


PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR  GENDER
1           john lennon     1940        M
2           johnny depp     19xx        M
3           johnny walker   19xx        M


PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR  GENDER  ROLE
2           johnny depp     19xx        M       hacker
3           johnny walker   19xx        M       walker

----------------------------------------------------------------


update actor set 
  role = 'pirates', birth_year = 1963
where person_name = 'johnny depp';

select * from person;

select * from actor;



Output:

PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR  GENDER
1           john lennon     1940        M
2           johnny depp     1963        M
3           johnny walker   19xx        M



PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR  GENDER  ROLE
2           johnny depp     1963        M       pirates
3           johnny walker   19xx        M       walker




----------------------------------------------------------------


delete from actor where person_name = 'johnny depp';

select * from person;

select * from actor;


Output:

PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR    GENDER
1           john lennon     1940          M
3           johnny walker   19xx          M

PERSON_ID   PERSON_NAME     BIRTH_YEAR    GENDER  ROLE
3           johnny walker   19xx          M       walker
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/463f4/1

Comment: I wish, I must use mySQL for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

INSERT INTO ACTOR (ACTOR_ID) SELECT P.PERSON_ID FROM PERSON P  LEFT JOIN  ACTOR A ON P.PERSON_ID=A.ACTOR_ID

Thanks
Rajath

Comment: Please help to increase the number of responses you get by asking better questions. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask